# How to represent formally, the state of a quantum computer at any given time?

Tags: quantum-state

Is there a way to mathematically represent the state of an arbitrary quantum computer (say a Ket) in a way such that the expression contains information about the components of the quantum computer (gates, registers, etc)?

Comment: I believe you are talking about two different things, the [state vector](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/representing-qubit-states.html#statevectors) which represents the state of the quantum computer at a given time and a [quantum circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_circuit) which represents a "formula" to calculate the evolution of the state vector

Comment: Welcome to Quantum Computing Stack Exchange. Could you give us more information and feedback on your question? Maybe also referencing places/images of what you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a quantum state that is a ket state $\vert \psi \rangle$, that is also the result of some quantum computation over another state, generally initially the $\vert 0\rangle$ state. Then, one can always write $\vert \psi \rangle = U_1 \circ \dots \circ U_n \vert 0 \rangle$ where $\circ$ denotes operatorial composition (letting $f:A\to B$ and $g: C\to A$ two functions, $f\circ g: C \to B$ is the function defined for any $c \in C$ as $f\circ g(c) = f(g(c)))$. Note that each unitary operation $U_i$ may be performed on many different parallel qubits in case we have $\vert 0 \rangle^{\otimes N}$ instead of a single Hilbert space. This also allows to construct a notion of complexity of constructing any quantum state. If you make post-selection on some of the qubits being used you can input dependencies on the unitaries with respect to the results obtained from outcomes on parts of the qubits used.